# Объявление функции без параметров

Tags: c++

Как правильно объявлять функцию без параметров в C++?

```
void func(void);
```

или

```
void func();
```

Answer (score 9):

В `C++` объявление функции без аргументов не требует явного прописывания слова `void`. Код с использованием `void` допускается из соображений совместимости с `C`, но в `C++` его следует избегать.

Comment: Всё дело в том, что Си и Си++ обрабатывают функцию с незаданными параметрами по-разному. Если в Си написать void funс() то программа не будет знать о количестве аргументов, тогда как в Си++ такая функция будет явно без параметров.

Answer (score 5):

файл: file1.c

```
int func1(void) { return 0; }
```

файл: filem.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func1();

int main() {
    printf("%d", func1(1));
}
```

Вот так, когда компилятор не делает предположений о параметрах функции func1 программа выведет то, что возвращает эта функтция.
Если поправить файл filem.c так чтобы объявление функции func1 соответствовало ее отределению:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func1(void);

int main() {
    printf("%d", func1(1));
}
```

То компилятор будет знать о том что мы не правы:

```
filem.c: In function ‘main’:
filem.c:10:18: error: too many arguments to function ‘func1’
     printf("%d", func1(1));
```

Впрочем в C++ это не актуально. Eго компилятор будет ругаться и без void